# Prevent Default Event in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to prevent the default event for a tags on my page in IE11.

I have tried the following which I got from other posts here on stack overflow:

```
  var preventThisInIE = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  preventThisInIE.forEach(function(item){
    item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
    });
  });
```

And

```
  var preventThisInIE = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  for(var i = 0; i < preventThisInIE.length; i++){
      preventThisInIE[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
    });
  }
```

Neither are working in IE11 and I am unsure why? Is there something incorrect with the Javascript above?

Comment: Why are you checking to see if `event.preventDefault` exists?

Comment: Works just fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/3gexwzdh/

Comment: Does it work in IE11?

Comment: yeah, your second fragment

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with my emulator then? I am on a mac currently

Comment: Your first code won't work without a polyfill, but your console should have told you that

Comment: I had also test your second code in IE 11 and it is working fine without any issue. I suggest you to make a test with IE application using any Windows machine may help you to see the accurate results.